# failed to resolve gradle build szagurskii

Tags: android, gradle

i been try to add grade build on dependencies into andriod studio. its says failed to resolve. i need help...

> failed to resolve com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0
>
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converted-gson:2.3.0'

Here my gradle build

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.wedee.com.wedeeapplication"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
 }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'

   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
   implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
   implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converted-gson:2.3.0'
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patternedtextwatcher is distributed via jCenter rather than Maven

https://bintray.com/zsavely/maven/patternedtextwatcher/0.5.0

Ensure you have jcenter in your project level build.gradle, something like this;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> failed to resolve com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0

You should add below in your ***PROJECT LEVEL*** `build.gradle` section.

You can use **[SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/zsavely/PatternedTextWatcher)**

```
implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Then

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
      maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
      }
    }
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run (With Internet)`**.

Comment: Let me inform .

Comment: i think is not working anymore. I am having troubles with it.